# Magento2: How to get the old qty of product?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7, cataloginventory

How to get the available qty of the product before saving the product with new qty in magento2.

How to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Event

Use the `catalog_product_save_after` event in the `Vendor/Model/etc/adminhtml/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="the_observer_name" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ProductSaveAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

### Observer

In the Observer, use the **$observer->getProduct()->getOrigData('...')** is the point to get specific attribute change.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductSaveAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        // you could add more product attributes to the $compareArray
        $compareArray = ['sku','price','special_price','cost','weight','special_from_date','special_to_date','status','visibility','is_salable'];
        $event = "";
        foreach ($compareArray as $value) {
            $old = $product->getOrigData($value);
            $new = $product->getData($value);
            if ($old !== $new) {
                $event .= " Change $value $old=>$new.";
            }
        }
        // other codes and write the $event to DB
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer. You are okay for products but just a warning that getOrigData doesnt work for all entities. 3 year old bug https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4662